# Object is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using singnalR hub and the variable "name" works fine with all other methods but getting "undefined" in the following method.

This method takes the "name" and add it to the list and finaly display the "name" in a div.

I pass the name like this-

```
function registerEvents(chatHub) {
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name");
    if (name.length > 0) {
        alert("error");
        chatHub.server.connect(name);
    }



 function AddUser(chatHub, id, name) {

    var userId = $('#hdId').val();

    var code = "";

    if (userId == id) {
        alert(name);
        code = $('<div class="loginUser">' + name + "</div>");

    }
    else {

        code = $('<a id="' + id + '" class="user" >' + name + '<a>');

        $(code).dblclick(function () {

            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            if (userId != id)
                OpenPrivateChatWindow(chatHub, id, name);

        });
    }
```

Comment: I have already done this

Answer (score 0):

You need to call AddUser method on new user connected

```
 // On New User Connected

 chatHub.client.onNewUserConnected   =
 function (id, name) {
 AddUser ( chatHub, id, name);
 }
```

Follow link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room